# Validate nested component form item from parent form with Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, ant-design-pro

Is there a way I can validate a nested component form item from its parent form when submitting?

Here is an example, *I know I could handle both items in the same form and this is not the best way to pass the data from child to parent component (It's just a simple example to illustrate my question). I have a more complex situation than this example.*.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { FormComponentProps } from "antd/lib/form/Form";
import { Input, Form } from "ant";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  const [childValue, setChildValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(state);
        console.log(childValue);
      }
    });
  };

  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Item
        label="Name"
        labelAlign="left"
        colon={false}
        labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 14 }}
        required={false}
      >
        {getFieldDecorator("name", {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true
            }
          ]
        })(
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="Name"
            onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <ChildComponent setChildValue={setChildValue} />
    </Form>
  );
}

const WrappedApp = Form.create({ name: "App" })(App);
export default WrappedApp;
```

ChildComponent.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Input, Form } from "antd";

function ChildComponent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setChildValue(state);
  }, [state]);

  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;
  return (
    <Form.Item
      label="Last"
      labelAlign="left"
      colon={false}
      labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
      wrapperCol={{ span: 14 }}
      required={false}
    >
      {getFieldDecorator("last", {
        rules: [
          {
            required: true
          }
        ]
      })(
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="Last"
          onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}
        />
      )}
    </Form.Item>
  );
}
export default ChildComponent;
```

When I submit the form from App.js, I want to also check the validation of item from the ChildComponent.js.
Is there a way I can pass a reference from App.js form to validate the item in ChildComponent?

P.s. 
I have tried passing `props.form` from App.js to ChildComponent.js. It didn't check the validation for the ChildComponent item.

Comment: Yes, firstly don't use `onChange` on uncontrolled form, secondly, you can validate using the `id` name like `"last"`, you can see examples in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but if you passed the form in the props of the child component, then you shouldn't need to execute setChildValue at all and the value of the child form values would be captured when handling submit.
So:

```
<ChildComponent form={form} />
```

then the child should be validated as well as the parent.